# Check a datetime in pythonlist and convert to string

Tags: python

```
lista = [datetimeobject,'test',32]
```

if any element in the list is a datetimeobject, I need to convert to date format(ie;`2012-01-01`) and wrap around a quote "'" ie;`'2012-01-01'`

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime
found_datetimes = []
DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"

for item in lista:
    if isinstance(item, datetime.datetime):
        found_datetimes.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(item, DATE_FORMAT))

print found_datetimes
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `repr(str())`:

```
In [17]: x=datetime.date(2012,2,5)

In [18]: str(x)              # actually returns repr(str(x)) in interactive prompt
Out[18]: '2012-02-05'

In [22]: print str(x)        # doesn't adds ''
2012-02-05

In [23]: print repr(str(x))  # get '' around solution
'2012-02-05'
```

for `datetime.datetime` object:

```
In [31]: str(y)
Out[31]: '2012-02-05 00:00:00'

In [32]: print repr(str(y)[:10])
'2012-02-05'
```

Comment: This doesn't get the `'` around it like requested (although your output *implies* it does to someone one familiar with the difference between `repr` and `str` and when each is called at the interactive prompt)...but that's pretty trivial to add.

Comment: nice solution, that will save me a lot of typing! (he was talking about datetime objects,tough, which will include the hours as well)

Comment: @AlexanderStefanov added the `datetime` object too.

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime

convert_date = lambda dt: dt.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'") if isinstance(dt, datetime) else dt
lista = [datetime.now(), 'test', 32]
map(convert_date, lista)
```

Returns:

```
["'2012-10-19'", 'test', 32]
```

Comment: Change to `dt.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'")` and you're all set.

Comment: Done. Thanks, I didn't realize the op actually wanted the single quotes in the string.